# Preserving Prestashop cart content between sessions

Tags: session, prestashop, cart

I was wondering if there is a way to share cart content between sessions in Prestashop 1.7: I noticed that, every time I logout, I loose all items added to the cart.
A further investigation on the database revealed that, when a user logs in, a new row is added to *ps_cart* table.

Does anyone know if it's possible to prevent creating a new cart every time you log in? Can you use only one "permanent" cart per user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there's an option for that.
Go to the Dashboard, click on Shop Parameters, then select Customer Settings and switch on YES under Re-display cart at login.